# How to prevent ArcGIS JS map from failing when using a Bootstrap "hidden" class?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, bootstrap-framework

I'm trying to put an ArcGIS Server JS API map within a div with a [hidden-sm](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes) class in Bootstrap 3, so that the map is not shown on small devices.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The map's parent div is correctly hidden when dragging a large window to become narrower on a desktop browser.

But when re-expanding the window such that the map's parent div displays again, the map is no longer functional.

[image]

Note that the div is shown but the map is empty, and the zoom buttons are non-functional.

How can I hide the map on a smaller device, without causing it to fail when the browser is expanded again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the map constructor options, set autoResize to false, eg:

```
var map = new Map("map", {
  basemap: "topo",
  center: [-122.45, 37.75], // longitude, latitude
  zoom: 13,
  autoResize: false
});
```

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#autoresize

Answer (score 1):

You could use map.resize(); fire it whenever the browser is resized or when the display attribute of the container changes (`dojo.on('id', 'resize', function(){})`). Works on most occasions.
Or you could use something like `map.redraw()` or `map.refresh()` (https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer.html#redraw). Key is to tap into the window resize event

I haven't tested it with your example. Perhaps you could provide your example in jsfidle or something to make it easier to debug btw? I transferred yours to http://jsfiddle.net/9kgsLx5b/2/.

Comment: Thanks Dennis, that's a very useful start. Further testing shows that show/hide on the parent div (which I thought is all that Bootstrap's hidden class is doing) doesn't cause the problem. I'll keep testing....